# Firestore Rules - Permission Denied - Android Access

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My project structure is as follows:

```
project/DOCUMENT1/COLLECTION1/DOCUMENT2/COLLECTION2/

documentA
documentB
documentC ...
```

I would like to access the documents only at this level at this time. I understand that rules must point to a document or can use a wildcard to point to any document in a collection, but I cannot get it to work in Android (Permission Denied).

My current rule is this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /DOCUMENT1/COLLECTION1/DOCUMENT2/COLLECTION2/{doc} {
        allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tested successful access in Android by receiving the data from `project/document` but I would like to go deeper into the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible**

So, after a lot of searching, the short answer is I, nor anyone else, can do this (yet).

The hierarchy must be flattened to only contain top-level collections and documents within each of those - no deeper.

This is fine for what I'm doing. Thankfully I haven't populated a database as yet.